# Jquery animation of a div to display after some load time

Tags: jquery, html

I have a div. I want to animate this div like a popup window. The div will only animate after some time period of page load. for example i want to animate after 5 minute of page load

Comment: Please post your code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this with delay() function. You can use delay function

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#div1").delay("slow").fadeIn();
    $("#div2").delay("fast").fadeIn();
    $("#div3").delay(800).fadeIn();
    $("#div4").delay(2000).fadeIn();
    $("#div5").delay(4000).fadeIn();

  });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p>This example sets different speed values for the delay() method.</p>
<button>Click to fade in boxes with a delay</button>
<br><br>
<div id="div1" style="width:90px;height:90px;display:none;background-color:black;"></div><br>
<div id="div2" style="width:90px;height:90px;display:none;background-color:green;"></div><br>
<div id="div3" style="width:90px;height:90px;display:none;background-color:blue;"></div><br>
<div id="div4" style="width:90px;height:90px;display:none;background-color:red;"></div><br>
<div id="div5" style="width:90px;height:90px;display:none;background-color:purple;"></div><br>


</body>
</html>
```

If you want to hide them.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#div1").delay("slow").fadeIn();
    $("#div2").delay("fast").fadeIn();
    $("#div3").delay(800).fadeIn();
    $("#div4").delay(2000).fadeIn();
    $("#div5").delay(4000).fadeIn(function(){

 $("#div1").delay("slow").fadeOut();
    $("#div2").delay("fast").fadeOut();
    $("#div3").delay(1000).fadeOut();
    $("#div4").delay(2000).fadeOut();
$("#div5").delay(4000).fadeOut();
});

  });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p>This example sets different speed values for the delay() method.</p>
<button>Click to fade in boxes with a delay</button>
<br><br>
<div id="div1" style="width:90px;height:90px;display:none;background-color:black;"></div><br>
<div id="div2" style="width:90px;height:90px;display:none;background-color:green;"></div><br>
<div id="div3" style="width:90px;height:90px;display:none;background-color:blue;"></div><br>
<div id="div4" style="width:90px;height:90px;display:none;background-color:red;"></div><br>
<div id="div5" style="width:90px;height:90px;display:none;background-color:purple;"></div><br>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't forget to like.

Comment: What you mean? Now this delay out automatically.

Comment: that means after 5 second i need the div come back in original position

Comment: by using fade out the div will disappear. I need to hide only the animation changes

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function()
      {
      $("#btn1").click(function(){
        $("#box").animate({height:"300px"});
        $("#box").delay(5000).animate({height:"100px"});
      });

    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <button id="btn1">Animate height</button>

    <div id="box" style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;margin:6px;">
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Also i need to display a message in the animated div. Also remove this message after the animation

Comment: Use setTimeout function. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_settimeout